# How to persist XMLDocument during post back?

Tags: vb.net, postback, xmldocument, persist

How to presist XML Document on Post Back?

I have this xmlDocument to persist in SaveViewState() method:

```
    Private _xmlSaveDispatch As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument
```

In my Page_Load...

```
If Not IsPostBack Then 
   Me._xmlSaveDispatch = New XmlDocument 

Private Property XMLSaveDispatch As XmlDocument 
  Get 
    Return _xmlSaveDispatch 
  End Get 

  Set(value As XmlDocument) 
      _xmlSaveDispatch = value 
  End Set 
End Property 

Button Click Event: 
Protected Sub dispatchButton_OnSave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _ 
     Handles dispatchButtons.SaveDispatch 
   XMLSaveDispatch = _objDispatchInfo.GetSaveXML() 
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this VB.NET and ASP.NET? The question is unclear. What are you trying to send from the browser and what want you to persist?

Comment: Sorry for unclear question:
I have XML Document which loads and xml string on button click...but that button is Server Button and it does post back and lost value. I to persist that XML Document?

Comment: Can you share just the code that shows the Button_click handler and add it to your question?

Comment: Private _xmlSaveDispatch As XmlDocument

In my Page_Load...
            If Not IsPostBack Then
                Me._xmlSaveDispatch = New XmlDocument


Private Property XMLSaveDispatch As XmlDocument
            Get
                Return _xmlSaveDispatch
            End Get
            Set(value As XmlDocument)
                _xmlSaveDispatch = value
            End Set
        End Property

Button Click Event:

Protected Sub dispatchButton_OnSave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dispatchButtons.SaveDispatch
      XMLSaveDispatch = _objDispatchInfo.GetSaveXML()
End Sub

Comment: this is going nowhere. What is being posted back? fields? files? what is GetSaveXml doing?

Answer (score 0):

I am writing a C# application and ran into the same issue (the asp:Xml tag does not persist between postbacks). Here is my code to persist it in C#:

```
//.aspx Presentation
<asp:Xml ID="xmlFormDisplay" runat="server"></asp:Xml>

//.aspx.cs Code Behind
private string formXSLT
{
    get { return ViewState["FormXSLT"].ToString(); }
    set { ViewState["FormXSLT"] = value; }
}
private string formXML
{
    get { return ViewState["FormXML"].ToString(); }
    set { ViewState["FormXML"] = value; }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
         ...
    }

    xmlFormDisplay.TransformSource = formXSLT;
    xmlFormDisplay.DocumentContent = formXML;
}
```

I'm not much of a VB developer, but this ought to work (or be pretty close):

```
//.aspx Presentation
<asp:Xml ID="xmlFormDisplay" runat="server"></asp:Xml>

//.aspx.vb Code Behind
Private Property FormXSLT As String
    Get 
        Return ViewState["FormXSLT"].ToString() 
    End Get 
    Set(value As String) 
        ViewState["FormXSLT"] = value 
    End Set 
End Property

Private Property FormXML As String
    Get 
        Return ViewState["FormXML"].ToString() 
    End Get 
    Set(value As String) 
        ViewState["FormXML"] = value 
    End Set 
End Property

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then 
         ...
    End If

    xmlFormDisplay.TransformSource = formXSLT
    xmlFormDisplay.DocumentContent = formXML
End Sub
```